# Simple query with criteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

How can I do to execute this HQL query with CRITERIA?

```
select c.id, c.field1 of Entity c;
```

I do not want a list of entities "Entity", I want an array of objects with

```
position [0] = "c.id" and position [1] "c.field1";
```

I try some solutions, but I could not do this job.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Projection and a Transformer

```
Entity entityAlias = null;
SomeDto dtoAlias = null;

_session.QueryOver(() => entityAlias)                   
                .SelectList(
                    list =>
                    list.Select(() => entityAlias.Id)
                        .WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.Id)
                        .Select(() => entityAlias.Field1)
                        .WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.Field1))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SomeDto>());
```